# How to delete a specific data/object in an object? (ReactJs Reducer)

Tags: reactjs

If my context is like this

```
const [data, dispatch] = useReducer(dataReducer, {
        projects:{},
        tasks:{},
    });
```

and the data was

```
 {
        projects:{
        'first':{
            name:'first',
            taskIds:['task-1'],
        },
        'second':{
             name:'second',
            taskIds:['task-2','task-3'],
        },
        },
        tasks:{
            'task-1':{
                title:'Eat',
                time:'1:30pm',
            },
            'task-2':{
                title:'Work',
                time:'2:30pm',
            },
            'task-3':{
                title:'Sleep',
                time:'9:00pm',
            },
        },
}
```

How can i delete 'task-2' inside the  projects.second and tasks objects by using a reducer?

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, you will need to replicate the object without 'task-2' from projects and tasks and pass it as a new state because objects inside an object requires a special action called 'deep copy'. Therefore, I suggest that you should separate projects and tasks since reducer requires a whole object to update the current state to new state.

Then, you can pass each reducer an object you want to pass as such:

tasks:

```
 // tasks
 {
        tasks:{
            'task-1':{
                title:'Eat',
                time:'1:30pm',
            },
            'task-3':{
                title:'Sleep',
                time:'9:00pm',
            },
        },
}
```

projects:

```
// projects
{
        projects:{
        'first':{
            name:'first',
            taskIds:['task-1'],
        },
        'second':{
             name:'second',
            taskIds:['task-3'],
        },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let projects = action.projects
let tasks = action.tasks
delete tasks['task-2']
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.